# Zsh filename expansion over multiple directories recursively

Tags: zsh

Problem: I have a directory $BASE, and in this directory (and/or any of the directories below it) are zero or more directory entries matching the pattern `*.x`. I want to loop over all these entries. I want to use `foreach` and not `find $BASE -name '*.x'` for this procedure. I have zsh 5.3.

My current approach goes like this:

```
foreach f in $BASE/*.x(N) $BASE/**/*.x(N)
do
  # ... do something with $f
done
```

Is there a way to write the glob pattern more uniformely (not requiring the repetition of `*.x`)?

Comment: `**` already matches 0 intermediate directories; why do you need the duplicate?

Comment: Indeed! I must have made a mistake when checking this (because I thought too initially that `**` should behavethis way). If you make your comment an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0):

`foreach f in $BASE/**/*.x(N)` is sufficient. `**` already matches *0* or more directories, so the pattern matches `$BASE/*.x` already.